# Is there any way to force UILocalNotification to be an alert by default?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm looking for a way to make UILocalNotifcations alerts by default.

Since banners are limited in terms of option selection, I'd like to make alerts the default type of notification.

```
let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
```

the line above is not sufficient, it keeps setting the default type of notification to banner.

Informing user to go to settings and change it into alarms is such a bad UX.

Comment: no. it depends on ipad setting.

Comment: and I'm asking how to change the default setting from code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible since it depends on the settings set by the user.

According to the docs:

> The user can change the notification settings for your app at any time
>   using the Settings app. Because settings can change, always call the
>   registerUserNotificationSettings: at launch time and use the
>   application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings: method to get the
>   response. If the user disallows specific notification types, avoid
>   using those types when configuring local and remote notifications for
>   your app.
>   [1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html)